# Approximating global extrema with the extrema of subsets of parameters

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms, maxima-minima

I don't have a particularly strong background on math;
I have a function of many boolean parameters $\theta_i$ :

$$ y = f( \theta_1 , ...., \theta_n ) $$

And I look for the values of the parameters where $y$ is maximum.
In order to limit the number of calculations, I intuitively divided the parameters into subsets :

$$ \Theta_1 = \{ \theta_1, ..., \theta_i \} $$
$$ \Theta_2 = \{ \theta_{i+1}, ..., \theta_j \} $$
$$ \Theta_3 = \{ \theta_{j+1}, ..., \theta_n \} $$

I first looked for the values $(\Theta_1)_1, (\Theta_1)_2, ...$ of $\Theta_1$ where $y$ is maximum when the other subsets have all their values set to "true".
I then did the same with each of the other subsets.

I finally looked for the combinations of the different values of the subset where $y$ is maximum (e.g. $(\Theta_1)_1$ with $(\Theta_2)_5$ and $(\Theta_3)_4$), and I considered it as an approximation of the global maximum.

Does this method have a name ?
Is it the greedy algorithm ?

Thank you

Comment: From a probability standpoint, the result is *likely* to be near the actual maximum. But unless you have some additional information about about the behavior of $f$ not shared here, there is some chance it could return a result well short of the actual maximum, possible even near the bottom.

Comment: Yes that's true, that's why it reminds me of the Greedy algorithm as it has similar limits; However, the method seems more specific here. I found some research work on the optimization of functions like $f$, it mentions subsets fixing but I'm still reading it: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X01003419